# React Router access params from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am currently looking into React.js & Redux and was playing around with react-router. My question is: Is there a way to access url params from another Component?

For example:

I have a `Foo` component which displays the `:bar` param (via `props.match.params.bar`), but I also want to display the value of `:bar` in the Header Component. With `ReactRouterDOM.withRouter` I can get access to `props.match`. The Problem is that this is not the same as in the `Foo` Component (it contains the information about the parent route '/'). So how do I get the value in the `Header` Component and am I even on the right track?

Thanks in advance

```js
const Foo = (props) => {
    return (<div> <h1> Foo {props.match.params.bar} </h1> </div>);
};

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <HeaderWrapper />
            <h1> Hello App </h1>
            <p><ReactRouterDOM.Link to='/foo/bar'>Foo Bar</ReactRouterDOM.Link></p>
            <hr />
        
            <ReactRouterDOM.Route path='/foo/:bar' component={Foo} />
        </div>);
};

// Header
const Header = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return ( <header> <small>You are here: {}</small>  </header>);
};
const HeaderWrapper = ReactRouterDOM.withRouter(Header);

// Router
ReactDOM.render((
        <ReactRouterDOM.MemoryRouter>
            <ReactRouterDOM.Route path='/' component={App} />
        </ReactRouterDOM.MemoryRouter >
 ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, react-router doesn't have any standard way to achieve what you need. But you can use regular expression with [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) library to do that manually. You will always get the correct result as react-router it self internally use this library to match routes.

```
const re = pathToRegexp('/foo/:bar')
const result = re.exec(props.location.pathname)
if(result){
    console.log(result[1]); //bar
}
```